# Show that G'(x)=f(v(x))*v'(x) for all x in [c,d]

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f:[a,b]\to R$ be continuous on [a,b] and let $v: [c,d]\to R$ be differentiable on $[c,d]$ with $v([c,d])$ subset of [a,b]. If we define $G(x):= \int_{a}{^{v(x)}}f$, show that $G'(x)=f(v(x))*v'(x)$ for all $x\in[c,d]$

my answer:
Using this theorem: if f is continuous on [a,b], then the indefinite integral F, defined by $F(z)= \int_{a}{^{v(x)}}f$  for $z\in[a,b]$, is differentiable on [a,b] and $F'(x)=f(x$) for all $x\in[a,b]$
and using the Chain Rule

$G(x)= \int_{a}{^{v(x)}}f = f(v(x)) - f(a)$
applying Chain rule
$G'(x)=f(v(x))*v'(x) - 0$

is this enough to show that this is for all $x\in[c,d]$?

Comment: This site uses MathJax formatting of formulas. http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right way, but there are some  mistakes in your proof.

Define the function $F \: \colon [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
\begin{equation}
F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(s) \, \textrm{d} s.
\end{equation}
Then, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $F$ is continuously differentiable in $(a,b)$ with $F'(x) = f(x)$ for $x \in (a,b)$. Let us now define $G \: \colon [c,d] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by 
\begin{equation}
G(z) = \int_{a}^{v(z)} f(s) \, \textrm{d}s = F(v(z)).
\end{equation}
Then $G$ is a composition of two continuously differentiable functions, and hence continuously differentiable as well. Using the product rule, we find that
\begin{equation}
G'(z) = F'(v(z)) \cdot v'(z)
\end{equation}
for all $z \in (c,d)$.